The relationship between World building and Narrative/Story
Whilst answering another question, I used an example that struck me as having something of interest about it:
Imagine that George Lucas, back in the 1970s, was a member of Worldbuilding - and he asked the following question:
I need my superweapon to have a critical vulnerability and the hero needs to fly a dangerous course and use a physical missile (that only he has the skill to aim and fire) to attack it - How can I do this
We would rightfully close this as too story based (as well as a discussion - but CBF writing a full question about a New Hope as an example).
And yet...
There is a line in the movie - that IS a Worldbuilding line - they say it is Ray Shielded and so they can only use proton torpedoes.
And although a bit of a throw-away line, it is pivotal in setting up the final climactic scenes of the Movie.
Often times, questions that are rightfully closed as too story based do have either the potential to become worldbuilding questions or have a valid world building answer.
It is here that my curiosity was piqued:
If we accept that in some instances, a story-based question has a world building element, how can we help the members of WB:SE who are stuck on a particular plot point or are otherwise in-need of a World building justification for a key element in their story to frame their questions in such a way that we can answer?

Related: Can we establish a chat room for plot?

It'll be just like Beggar's Canyon back home.

Personally, I think it's fairly simple. We've got all the tools to help George answer his question. We just need to use them! Whenever I see a story-building query like this, my first thought is one of perspective. What am I seeing from the external perspective that George isn't seeing from his internal perspective. Essentially, we just need to nudge the Author into a place where he can see as we do. He's already got the world built; he's already got the story mapped out. Because of current Rules, we can't answer directly. But! We can very often jiggle the question around until it lines up just right with the Rules!

If we compare the Author to a 2D person approaching a box, what he sees is a line: he's thinking in terms of plot, of narrative, of how do I go from A to B to C. He's become so immersed in the words that he literally can't see anything other than what his characters are seeing.

Our job is simply to remind the Author that he is actually a 3D person. We just have to lift him out of Flatland and rebroaden his perspective. As his rightful 3D self, he can now look inside the box: he can now see all the lines that describe the box as well as the contents of the box.

We would do this by asking George for clarifications in comments! We might literally say: Okay, you've got a sequence of events, and you've got narrative necessity (the super weapon must be destroyed); so let's take a look at the rules of your world. Tell us about what kinds of weapons, armaments, defense schemes, etc. we've got to work with. We could also use the narrative arc itself as a quasi rule of the world, so we can legally ask about that too.

Working back and forth, we'd learn that there are cute little guns that go "pew!-pew!" and lasers and a variety of physical and energy shielding schemes. We'd learn that all of these things exist within the context of a David vs Goliath struggle of a small Rebel force going up against a well funded governmental behemoth.

He could then evolve his query from "I need my superweapon to have a critical vulnerability and the hero needs to fly a dangerous course and use a physical missile (that only he has the skill to aim and fire) to attack it - How can I do this?" to a more WB.SE friendly "I've got a vulnerable superweapon that needs to be destroyed: would it make sense for this scrappy drag-racing, crop-dusting pilot to drop some kind of physical missile into the weak spot of the weapon?"

With these constraints in mind, we could then come up with some potential answers that make use of the rules of the world coupled with what George has written about his characters. Scrappy young crop-duster / barn-storming / drag-racing pilots + a dangerous & narrow course + "ray shielding" = "It'll be just like Beggar's Canyon back home!"

Before I read the rest of this - you should get a +1 just on the Star Wars reference alone.


I need my superweapon to have a critical vulnerability and the hero needs to fly a dangerous course and use a physical missile (that only he has the skill to aim and fire) to attack it - How can I do this

Just to be clear - this is an absolutely atrocious example for a worldbuilding question. See why

There is a line in the movie - that IS a Worldbuilding line - they say it is Ray Shielded and so they can only use proton torpedoes.

It could have as easily been "Today is Thursday and The Intergalactic Frog forbids us shooting from afar on Thursdays, therefore we need to get close."
Yes, it barely holds together. But it achieves the same thing in the end:

And although a bit of a throw-away line, it is pivotal in setting up the final climactic scenes of the Movie.

The actual rationalisation does not matter. It is just technobabble to set up the excuse for the scene. Other things that would achieve the same effect:

Defence systems can intercept and shoot down long-ranged weapons. So, the pilots have to get in close for a dramatic scene.
The rebels have run out of long-ranged options. The empire has been cutting off their supply lines. So, they only have the short-ranged weapons to use.
A malfunction in the targetting computers means long-range is out of question. The only desperate option is to get in close.
The Force does not allow it.

And so on. Again, the line does not matter. It is only there to serve the plot and set up the cinematography of having a cool-and-risky looking scene.

Who's needs are we meeting?
In a sense, what you're asking is, "given any story-based question, can't we just change it into a worldbuilding question and answer it?"
While I see your point, we cannot read the querent's mind. While we, looking in from the outside, may see a way to convert the question into a worldbuilding question, that choice may not reflect the goals or intent of the querent at all.
The stated goal of the Stack is:

Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds. (Help Center)

Changing the question to meet the above expectation assumes we know better than the querent what the querent needs. In reality, what we're doing to recreating the question to be what we need.
Impatience has always been our weakness
Very few of us are willing to hold back, to choose not to answer a question until the querent has provided additional details or otherwise fixed their question. That's actually the preferred solution: to explain that how they asked their question is off-topic and to ask them if what they meant or need help with is X? "X" being the worldbuilding-centered solution.
This, of course, presupposes that the querent has the slightest idea of what we're talking about or enough experience in the worldbuilding and storybuilding processes to recognize the difference. It doesn't help that a lot of people really are looking for help writing their stories and it only looks, from the outside looking in, like it could be or should be help worldbuilding. In otherwords, they're writing their stories and building their worlds at the same time.
And that's a problem. At least for us.
Having said all that
If I ever get around to finishing the Help Center upgrade project, we've already accepted that we should begin to accept story-based questions.
But it's not that simple!
We can't just open the gates. We're stuck with the Tour, the Help Center, etc., as written and without changing them we're imposing an ideology on top of an existing rule set. Better known as anarchy, the result is chaos.
So... patience... right now we can't just change people's questions to meet our needs. We need to change us to meet their needs. What I've learned so far is that's a whomping lot of work (at least to do it right...).
What's the solution today? To talk to the querent and make absolutely sure that a worldbuilding problem is what they're really trying to solve.
To be fair, your example isn't as too-story-based as you think. It has limitations and requirements and is asking for a way to rationalize a technology. The only thing missing from the "question" is the interface between the pilot and the super weapon: the exhaust port. Had that been identified, I believe it would have been a fine worldbuilding question. But because it's not included, anything and everything could be suggested as the potential weakness. In other words, the question should have included "the weakness is the exhaust port, but how to I protect it such that the pilot is forced to use missiles?" Then it becomes an acceptable development-of-technology question.
